# How to get the friends' posts on a facebook user's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been searching a lot for a way to get the `posts` made by the `user's friends` on his **Facebook** wall, but all what I reached is that I can only Post on `friends`' walls but I cant retrieve what they  posted on the `user's` wall, so Is this correct or is there a way to retrieve these information?

Note that I reached an **FQL Query** as follows

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE actor_id=actorID and source_id = me()
```

but unfortunately it returned an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been testing what you said and it is correct. It is returning an empty array. There is a small detail that we are missing and that is the LIMIT.
By default the limit of the posts that it will be returned is a small one and there is a big possibility that the required post is not found in that limit.
The solution is the following:

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE actor_id=actorID and source_id = me() limit 100
```

If you still get an empty array try increasing the limit. This worked fine with me though.